# Wiki: Improve hector_mapping description w.r.t. odometry

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The summary of [hector_mapping](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_mapping) says:

> hector_mapping is a SLAM approach that can be used without odometry as well as  on platforms [...]

This does not make it clear that the mapping *cannot* be improved by available external odometry. I suggest changing this to

> hector_mapping is a SLAM approach that does not use odometry and can be used  on platforms [...]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210158/wiki:-improve-hector_mapping-description-w.r.t.-odometry/) by [jondo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22518/jondo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The wiki is actually a *wiki*, so anyone can change it. If you feel this is an improvement, please register for an account and update the page.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jondo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22518/jondo/) on 2015-05-29**:
Good point! But it seems I can only edit the part starting with **1. Overview**. Can I also edit the PackageHeader(hector_mapping) somewhere?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-05-29**:
That part of the page is auto-generated from the [package manifest](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam/blob/c91a49344f081b34dc53a410a4a39399bf5410fa/hector_mapping/package.xml). You'll have to submit a PR against that repo and see if the authors accept it.

**Comment by [jondo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22518/jondo/) on 2015-06-15**:
I have filed [an issue](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam/issues/21) there.